# Is there any way to store some information that can be read when the device is discovered?

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, flutter-dependencies

Is there any way to create/re-use some property for a Bluetooth device that can be read on discovery and can be used by a custom service?

eg. MAC address and name could be considered as two such properties

Is there any other property apart from it that can satisfy the given requirement?

Comment: Why did you delete the answer?

Comment: I only wanted to know how could I change the advertising data using that Flutter plugin